# PDO prepared statements in PHP not allowing more than 5 columns in the table

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, insert, prepared-statement

As the title says, I'm having problems trying to use a pre-made wrapper class for [PDO prepared statements](https://code.google.com/p/php-pdo-wrapper-class/). I'm not able to insert more than 5 values at a time in one row, this is the first time I have ever encountered this error in my programing days. Here is the class source code, and first attempt at implementation;

```
class db extends PDO {
private $error;
private $sql;
private $bind;
private $errorCallbackFunction;
private $errorMsgFormat;

public function __construct($dsn, $user="", $passwd="") {
    $options = array(
        PDO::ATTR_PERSISTENT => true, 
        PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE => PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION
    );
    try {
        parent::__construct($dsn, $user, $passwd, $options);
    } catch (PDOException $e) {
        $this->error = $e->getMessage();
    }
}

private function debug() {
    if(!empty($this->errorCallbackFunction)) {
        $error = array("Error" => $this->error);
        if(!empty($this->sql))
            $error["SQL Statement"] = $this->sql;
        if(!empty($this->bind))
            $error["Bind Parameters"] = trim(print_r($this->bind, true));

        $backtrace = debug_backtrace();
        if(!empty($backtrace)) {
            foreach($backtrace as $info) {
                if($info["file"] != __FILE__)
                    $error["Backtrace"] = $info["file"] . " at line " . $info["line"];  
            }       
        }

        $msg = "";
        if($this->errorMsgFormat == "html") {
            if(!empty($error["Bind Parameters"]))
                $error["Bind Parameters"] = "<pre>" . $error["Bind Parameters"] . "</pre>";
            $css = trim(file_get_contents(dirname(__FILE__) . "/error.css"));
            $msg .= '<style type="text/css">' . "\n" . $css . "\n</style>";
            $msg .= "\n" . '<div class="db-error">' . "\n\t<h3>SQL Error</h3>";
            foreach($error as $key => $val)
                $msg .= "\n\t<label>" . $key . ":</label>" . $val;
            $msg .= "\n\t</div>\n</div>";
        }
        elseif($this->errorMsgFormat == "text") {
            $msg .= "SQL Error\n" . str_repeat("-", 50);
            foreach($error as $key => $val)
                $msg .= "\n\n$key:\n$val";
        }

        $func = $this->errorCallbackFunction;
        $func($msg);
    }
}

public function delete($table, $where, $bind="") {
    $sql = "DELETE FROM " . $table . " WHERE " . $where . ";";
    $this->run($sql, $bind);
}

private function filter($table, $info) {
    $driver = $this->getAttribute(PDO::ATTR_DRIVER_NAME);
    if($driver == 'sqlite') {
        $sql = "PRAGMA table_info('" . $table . "');";
        $key = "name";
    }
    elseif($driver == 'mysql') {
        $sql = "DESCRIBE " . $table . ";";
        $key = "Field";
    }
    else {  
        $sql = "SELECT column_name FROM information_schema.columns WHERE table_name = '" . $table . "';";
        $key = "column_name";
    }   

    if(false !== ($list = $this->run($sql))) {
        $fields = array();
        foreach($list as $record)
            $fields[] = $record[$key];
        return array_values(array_intersect($fields, array_keys($info)));
    }
    return array();
}

private function cleanup($bind) {
    if(!is_array($bind)) {
        if(!empty($bind))
            $bind = array($bind);
        else
            $bind = array();
    }
    return $bind;
}

public function insert($table, $info) {
    $fields = $this->filter($table, $info);
    $sql = "INSERT INTO " . $table . " (" . implode($fields, ", ") . ") VALUES (:" . implode($fields, ", :") . ");";
    $bind = array();
    foreach($fields as $field)
        $bind[":$field"] = $info[$field];
    return $this->run($sql, $bind);
}

public function run($sql, $bind="") {
    $this->sql = trim($sql);
    $this->bind = $this->cleanup($bind);
    $this->error = "";

    try {
        $pdostmt = $this->prepare($this->sql);
        if($pdostmt->execute($this->bind) !== false) {
            if(preg_match("/^(" . implode("|", array("select", "describe", "pragma")) . ") /i", $this->sql))
                return $pdostmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
            elseif(preg_match("/^(" . implode("|", array("delete", "insert", "update")) . ") /i", $this->sql))
                return $pdostmt->rowCount();
        }   
    } catch (PDOException $e) {
        $this->error = $e->getMessage();    
        $this->debug();
        return false;
    }
}

public function select($table, $where="", $bind="", $fields="*") {
    $sql = "SELECT " . $fields . " FROM " . $table;
    if(!empty($where))
        $sql .= " WHERE " . $where;
    $sql .= ";";
    return $this->run($sql, $bind);
}

public function setErrorCallbackFunction($errorCallbackFunction, $errorMsgFormat="html") {
    //Variable functions for won't work with language constructs such as echo and print, so these are replaced with print_r.
    if(in_array(strtolower($errorCallbackFunction), array("echo", "print")))
        $errorCallbackFunction = "print_r";

    if(function_exists($errorCallbackFunction)) {
        $this->errorCallbackFunction = $errorCallbackFunction;  
        if(!in_array(strtolower($errorMsgFormat), array("html", "text")))
            $errorMsgFormat = "html";
        $this->errorMsgFormat = $errorMsgFormat;    
    }   
}

public function update($table, $info, $where, $bind="") {
    $fields = $this->filter($table, $info);
    $fieldSize = sizeof($fields);

    $sql = "UPDATE " . $table . " SET ";
    for($f = 0; $f < $fieldSize; ++$f) {
        if($f > 0)
            $sql .= ", ";
        $sql .= $fields[$f] . " = :update_" . $fields[$f]; 
    }
    $sql .= " WHERE " . $where . ";";

    $bind = $this->cleanup($bind);
    foreach($fields as $field)
        $bind[":update_$field"] = $info[$field];

    return $this->run($sql, $bind);
}
}   
        $db = new db("mysql:host=xxxx;dbname=xxxx", 'xxxxx', "xxxxx");


        $insert = array(
                    "network" => "High",
                    "to" => "High",
                    "from" => "High",
                    "headerType" => "High",
                    "date" => "High",
                    "priority" => "High",
                    "content" => "High"                     
                        );


        $db->insert("email_queue", $insert);
```

Any help would be appropriated!

Comment: Instead of posting your entire class, do you think you can whittle it down to only the relevant portions of code? (which may even help to spot the problem by yourself).

Comment: Note, `date` is a reserved word, it needs backticks if you want to use it as an identifier of a column.

Comment: @Wrikken, `DATE` is not a MySQL reserved word.  http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/reserved-words.html

Comment: Well, I'll be... could've sworn... I stand corrected.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've tested this wrapper and it works with 6-fields inserts. Proof:

```
<?php
ini_set('display_errors', true);
require_once __DIR__.'/class.db.php';
$db = new db('mysql:host=127.0.0.1;dbname=test', 'root', '');

$db->setErrorCallbackFunction('echo', 'text');

$createTableQuery = <<<SQL
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `q17224744` (
  `name` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `lastname` varchar(100) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `gender` char(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `birthday` date NOT NULL,
  `city` varchar(100) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `country` char(2) NOT NULL DEFAULT ''
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
SQL;
$db->run($createTableQuery);

$db->insert('q17224744', array(
  'name' => 'John',
  'lastname' => 'Doe',
  'gender' => 'm',
  'birthday' => '1971-12-03',
  'city' => 'London',
  'country' => 'GB',
));
```

I assume your problem is about incorrect values in your insert. Wrapper lib wont say you about errors if you not set error callback function. Try to enable debug output with `setErrorCallbackFunction` function as in example above.

P.S. This wrapper has counterintuitive behavior - by default it says nothing when exception coming. It would be much better by default throw exception and silent only when programmer set exception handler.

Comment: The problem was 'to' and 'from' are reserved words in MYSQL. Thanks for putting me onto the idea and the error call back function!!

Comment: No problem. In future try to create more detailed questions :-)